# Go to XY Coordinate is 1:40000

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, zoom, xy

I am trying to use the "Go to XY Coordinate: tool. It used to zoom directly to the coordinates and now it is zooming to 1:38000. I am not sure why it has changed.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: 1:38000 is a scale not an XY point, so do you mean it used to zoom in closer to that point? Maybe go looking for a setting that sets a default zoom level for that tool?

Comment: Yes, it used to zoom in much closer to the coordinates. I have tried looking for the setting but haven't found it. That is why I posted the question here.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What are the precise and detailed steps that you perform when you see this, starting at when you start the application that you are using?